# Какие есть средства для просмотра фрагментации ОЗУ?

Tags: c++, windows, память, поиск-программ

### Есть ли какие-то средства для просмотра фрагментации ОЗУ?

Хочется видеть, как приложение выделяет память, потому что иногда получается, что из *32 ГБ* памяти занято *12-16 ГБ*, но занятая память сильно "разбросана", что не позволяет выделить кусок памяти *~10 ГБ*.

Я знаю про множество приложений для просмотра жестких дисков, но не нашел ни одного для просмотра RAM.

Ниже пример приложения для жесткого диска, нужно что-то похожее для оперативной памяти.

[image: Фрагментация жесткого диска]

Comment: Во-первых, программа сама решает, как она управляет своей собственной памятью, поэтому универсального способа быть не может. Во-вторых, во всех современных ОС память — виртуальная, и ОС при необходимости сама разобьёт большой кусок виртуальной памяти на несколько кусков реальной памяти (часть которой будет в оперативке, а часть может улететь в файл подкачки), поэтому никакая фрагментация мешать скорее всего не должна, всё должно прекрасно влезть в свободную оперативку по кускам, и значит у вас проблема скорее всего в чём-то другом

Comment: Увеличьте размер файла подкачки. Подозреваю что он у вас маленький. Сделайте его равным размеру оперативной памяти. Внутри процесса диапазон доступных адресов станет больше и у C++ будет шанс выделить большой блок.

Comment: Выделение блоков сравнимых с размером доступного адресного пространства - зло. В частности, из-за фрагментации. Попробуйте поменять структуры данных, что-бы этого не было. В C++ источник неприятностей обычно `vector`. Замените его на `deque`.

Comment: imho тут надо понять о чём идёт речь: память в системе (что не должно быть проблемой, если достаточно подкачки) или heap в программе...

Comment: А такой большой кусок в принципе может быть выделен в вашей ОС? Например, на пустой машине он выделяется?

Answer (score 2):

[утилита vmmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap) показывает блоки виртуального адресного пространства процесса и предоставляет средства для профилирования.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Профилировщик памяти в Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022). Gредоставляет средства для профилирования кучи для С++ приложений.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ну, в принципе, можно поиграться самостоятельно с [`HeapWalk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapwalk) (у вас же Windows?), например. Только тяжелая это работа, потому что даже пустая программа уже выделяет массу блоков памяти. Да и зависит от того, как менеджер памяти работает — он же может, например, запросить разово большой блок, а потом его уже внутри программы перераспределять. Так что сработает ли — зависит от массы факторов, в том числе от компилятора.

Просто как маленький пример —

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    HANDLE ph[20];
    int hCount = GetProcessHeaps(20,ph);

    char * q = new char[10000000];
    q[3] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < hCount; ++i)
    {
        PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY phe;
        phe.lpData = NULL;
        cout << "Heap #" << i << endl;

        for(;HeapWalk(ph[i],&phe);)
        {
            if (phe.wFlags & PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY_BUSY)
                cout << "    Block at " << phe.lpData << ", size " << phe.cbData << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

На VC++ 2022 у меня выдает список из почти 200 блоков памяти, который заканчивается

```
Block at 000002414B410FA0, size 18
Block at 000002414B410FD0, size 4096
Block at 000002414B546040, size 10000000
```

т.е. вот он, последний выделенный блок :)

Так что если желание есть — попробуйте, только не уверен, что просто информация о фрагментации как-то позволит ее уменьшить, не переделывая кардинально программу, типа написания собственных аллокаторов, или своего менеджера памяти, который в начале работы заберет один большой кусок памяти и сам будет ее перераспределять под ваши потребности.